# Solving a hyperbolic PDE via normal form

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The equation is $$4u_{xx}+5u_{xy}+u_{yy}+u_x+u_y=2$$

The equation is hyperbolic, for $b^2-ac=9/4>0$. Through characteristics I find the characteristic curves $$y-x=c_1,\enspace y-\frac{x}{4}=c_2$$

where $c_1,c_2$ are constants. Making the variable change $$\xi=y-x,\enspace \eta=y-\frac{x}{4}$$

yields the normal form $$u_{\xi \eta}-\frac{3}{15}u_{\eta}=\frac{8}{15}$$

How do I proceed from here? It should be sufficient to find one particular solution and the full homogenous solution. I think that the normal form might be a ODE for the variable $u_{\xi}$, differentiation being done with respect to $\eta$. The resulting constant of the solution would then be a function of $\eta$.

Comment: Substitute $v=\partial_\eta u$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea. Rewriting as
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} \left(u_\xi - \frac{1}{5} u \right) = \frac{8}{15}
$$
and then integrating w.r.t $\eta$ gives
$$
  u_\xi - \frac{1}{5} u = \frac{8}{15} \eta + f(\xi),
$$
where $f$ only depends on $\xi$. This is now a first order linear ODE in $u_\xi$. By multiplying both sides with $e^{-\xi/5}$,
$$
\begin{align*}
  e^{-\xi/5}\left(u_\xi - \frac{1}{5}u\right)
  &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}(e^{-\xi/5} u) 
  = e^{-\xi/5} \left[ -\frac{8}{15} \eta + f(\xi) \right] \\
\implies e^{-\xi/5} u &= \frac{8}{3}\eta e^{-\xi/5}
    + \int ^\xi _{s_0} f(s) e^{-s/5} ds + c \\
\implies u(\xi, \eta) &= \frac{8}{3}\eta 
    + e^{\xi/5} \int ^\xi _{s_0} f(s) e^{-s/5} ds + c e^{\xi/5} \\
\implies u(x, y) &= \frac{8}{3} y - \frac{2}{3} x 
    + e^{(y- x)/5} \int ^{y-x} _{s_0} f(s) e^{-s/5} ds + ce^{(x-y)/5} ,\\
\end{align*}
$$
which $s_0$ is a constant on the domain. To enforce the differetiability of $u$, we assume $f$ is continuous.

To see that the above $u$ is a solution you can compute its derivative. For example
$$
\begin{align*}
  u_x &= -\frac{2}{3} - f(y - x) 
     - \frac{1}{5} e^{(y- x)/5} \int ^{y-x} _{s_0} f(s) e^{-s/5} ds
     + \frac{c}{5} e^{(x -y)/5}, \\
  u_y &= \frac{8}{3} + f(y - x) +  \frac{1}{5} e^{(y- x)/5} \int ^{y-x} _{s_0} f(s) e^{-s/5} ds - \frac{c}{5} e^{(x -y)/5},
\end{align*} 
$$
so $2 - u_y - u_x = 0$. According to my calculations, $u_{xx} = u_{yy} = - u_{xy}$, hence the equality holds. I believe any function of the form
$$
  u(x, y) = \frac{8}{3} y - \frac{2}{3} x 
    + e^{(y- x)/a} \int ^{y-x} _{s_0} f(s) e^{-s/a} ds + ce^{(x-y)/a} 
    + const.
$$
where $a \neq 0$ is also a solution.